# How to gracefully iterate a date range in Go

Tags: go

I need to iterate any specified dates range, say 2017-12-21 to 2018-01-05. What is the best way to implement that in Go?

```
output：
20171221
20171222
20171223
...
20180104
20180105
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)
>
> A function literal represents an anonymous function.
>
> ```
> FunctionLit = "func" Signature FunctionBody .
>
> func(a, b int, z float64) bool { return a*b < int(z) }
> ```
>
> A function literal can be assigned to a variable or invoked directly.
>
> ```
> f := func(x, y int) int { return x + y }
> func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }(replyChan)
> ```
>
> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.

---

In Go, encapsulate complexity in functions. Use a function literal as a closure.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// rangeDate returns a date range function over start date to end date inclusive.
// After the end of the range, the range function returns a zero date,
// date.IsZero() is true.
func rangeDate(start, end time.Time) func() time.Time {
    y, m, d := start.Date()
    start = time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    y, m, d = end.Date()
    end = time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

    return func() time.Time {
        if start.After(end) {
            return time.Time{}
        }
        date := start
        start = start.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
        return date
    }
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    end := start.AddDate(0, 0, 6)
    fmt.Println(start.Format("2006-01-02"), "-", end.Format("2006-01-02"))

    for rd := rangeDate(start, end); ; {
        date := rd()
        if date.IsZero() {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(date.Format("2006-01-02"))
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wmfQC9fEs1S

Output:

```
2018-06-22 - 2018-06-28
2018-06-22
2018-06-23
2018-06-24
2018-06-25
2018-06-26
2018-06-27
2018-06-28
```

Comment: This code seems overly complex. I would suggest looking at @thenguyenit 's answer below.

Comment: This approach seems to be influenced by Python's generators.

Answer (score 52):

```
start := time.Now()
end := start.AddDate(0, 1, 0)
for d := start; d.After(end) == false; d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
    fmt.Println(d.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

Go play: https://play.golang.org/p/cFcaf-yfo0n

Comment: This is a much better solution, the approved one is certainly clever, but lacks the simplicity that go encourages.

Comment: Brilliant. clean and simple. should be approved.

Comment: One thing about the `d.After(end) == false` thing that caught me off guard. If both `d` and `end` are exactly the same instant, `end.After(d)` and `d.After(end) == false` will give different results. Be careful with that.

Comment: @guillemus do you have a reference for that behaviour? The golang documentation doesn't mention anything.

Answer (score 0):

we can implement generator pattern for such use case, for simplicity I've used buffered channel to avoid routine leak.

Ref: [oreilly: concurrency-in-go](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-go/9781491941294/ch04.html) for more understanding
[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Il9InMYmiwg)

```
// dates generates dates between start and end time (both included).
func dates(start, end time.Time) (dates <-chan time.Time) {
y, m, d := start.Date()
start = time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
y, m, d = end.Date()
end = time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
days := int(end.Sub(start).Hours()/24) + 1 // +1 to include both start and end date
if days < 0 {
    days = 0
}
ch := make(chan time.Time, days)
go func() {
    defer close(ch)
    for ;!start.After(end); start = start.AddDate(0,0,1){
        ch <- start
    }
}()
return ch
}
```